# Why does App crash during onCreate() with a java.lang.RuntimeException?

Tags: java, android

I need help about crash in app. Sometimes app crashes and i receive report that was java.lang.RuntimeException, android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class . Does anyone know what that can be?
Thanks.

```
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appcargo.driver/com.appcargo.driver.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class <unknown>
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2398)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3997)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1348)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5359)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class <unknown>
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3225)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3302)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:347)
           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1948)
           at com.appcargo.driver.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:286)
           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5368)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2352)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3997)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1348)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5359)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3225)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3302)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:347)
           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1948)
           at com.appcargo.driver.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:286)
           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5368)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2352)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3997)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1348)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5359)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010059 a=-1}
           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2331)
           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:613)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:123)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:109)
           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3225)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3302)
           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:347)
           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1948)
           at com.appcargo.driver.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:286)
           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5368)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2352)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3997)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1348)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5359)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Here is the xml file for reference:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/header" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.appcargo.driver.ui.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/new_drive_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/partly_transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <co.cargo.shared.ui.views.CustomTextViewRobotoBold
            android:id="@+id/ride_from_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/ride_from"
            android:textColor="@color/body_text_1"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/top_separator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/ride_from_label"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="@color/body_text_1" />

        <co.cargo.shared.ui.views.CustomTextViewRobotoLight
            android:id="@+id/from_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/top_separator"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Resavska 24"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ride_to_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/from_address">

            <co.cargo.shared.ui.views.CustomTextViewRobotoLight
                android:id="@+id/ride_to_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/ride_to"
                android:textColor="@color/body_text_1"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/bottom_separator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/ride_to_label"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:background="@color/body_text_1" />

            <co.cargo.shared.ui.views.CustomTextViewRobotoLight
                android:id="@+id/to_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/bottom_separator"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Ulcinjska 13"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/to_address">

            <co.cargo.shared.ui.views.CustomTextViewRobotoLight
                android:id="@+id/no_text_button"
                android:layout_width="128dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/no"
                android:textColor="@color/theme_accent"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <co.cargo.shared.ui.views.CustomTextViewRobotoLight
                android:id="@+id/yes_text_button"
                android:layout_width="128dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/yes"
                android:textColor="@color/theme_primary"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/arrived_btn"
        style="@style/ButtonGray"
        android:text="@string/arrived_btn"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_above="@+id/action_profile_btn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/client_picked_up_btn"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/client_picked_up_btn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/client_picked_up_btn"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/client_picked_up_btn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_ride_btn"
        style="@style/ButtonRed"
        android:text="@string/cancel_ride_btn"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/completed_btn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/action_profile_btn"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/action_profile_btn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/client_picked_up_btn"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/client_picked_up_btn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/client_picked_up_btn"
        style="@style/ButtonBlue"
        android:layout_above="@id/cancel_ride_btn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="@string/client_picked_up_btn"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/completed_btn"
        style="@style/ButtonGreen"
        android:text="@string/ride_completed_btn"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/action_profile_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/action_profile_btn"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/floating_action_btn"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/floating_action_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/user_action_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/logout_btn"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_action_btn"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_action_btn"
        android:layout_above="@id/action_profile_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_action_btn_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_action_btn_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_logout"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/show_profile_btn"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_action_btn"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_action_btn"
        android:layout_above="@id/logout_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_action_btn_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_action_btn_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_account"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/switch_availability_btn"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_action_btn"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_action_btn"
        android:layout_above="@id/show_profile_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_action_btn_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_action_btn_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/user_action_button_background"
        android:src="@drawable/user_action_on"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/action_route_btn"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/floating_action_btn"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/floating_action_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_car_button"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <com.appcargo.driver.ui.enums.SlideButton
        android:id="@+id/unlockButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
       android:thumb="@drawable/btn_completed"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_above="@+id/cancel_ride_btn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/arrived_btn"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/arrived_btn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/arrived_btn"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/arrived_btn"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_green"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/logout_btn" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="SLIDE TO COMPLETE RIDE"
        android:id="@+id/txtSlide"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/unlockButton"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_above="@+id/cancel_ride_btn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/arrived_btn"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/arrived_btn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/arrived_btn"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/arrived_btn"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="FirstName"
        android:id="@+id/txtFirstName"
        android:layout_weight="2.03"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/unlockButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/unlockButton"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/action_route_btn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/action_route_btn"
        android:visibility="gone" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show xml layout file.

Comment: show the xml layout and activity class file

Comment: Have you checked line 34 in your XML layout?

Comment: Post your code as well.

Comment: I posted my xml file.